# iOS self.delegate is nil even after being set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, viewcontroller

I have a controller that gets instantiated and pushed onto the navigation controller like this -

In ParentVC.m

```
ThingContainerViewController *thingContainer = [[ThingContainerViewController alloc] init];
thingContainer.delegate = self;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:thingContainer animated:YES];
```

Now I want to send back a value to ParentVC when the thingContainer is closed. So I have implemented a delegate as follows:

in ParentVC.h

```
@interface ParentVC : UIViewController <..., ThingContainerViewControllerDelegate>
```

in ThingContainer.h

```
@protocol ThingContainerViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addItemViewController:(id)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSInteger)page;
@end
....

@interface
....

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ThingContainerViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

....
@end
```

in ParentVC.m

```
- (void)addItemViewController:(id)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSInteger)page {
    self.page = page;
}
```

in ThingContainer.m

```
- (IBOutlet) ... closeButtonWasTapped:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexOfPage);
    [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishEnteringItem:indexOfPage];
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

At this point, self.delegate is null, so the method in the ParentVC never gets called. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: The delegate property should be `weak` but your question about `articleContainer` is valid.

Comment: Maybe you should set the delegate property of the thingContainer!? ;-)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad sorry, it was a mistake in pasting. I have set the correct delegate, but still does not work.

Comment: @Suchi could you show the whole method of ParentVC, where you create ThingContainer?

Comment: There is nothing else in that method. It is triggered on row selection of a table. @Brain89

Comment: Do you have any other points of ThingContainer creation and presentation? E.g. segues from storyboards?
You should check that ThingContainer object created in tableView delegate method is equal to closeButtonWasTapped handler object.